# how to reference user input in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've made this bit of code that seemingly worked.

```
set /p code=Color Code:
color %code%
cls
goto top
:top
echo Color Code: %code%
```

This works in that it changes the color of the window accordingly, however, I want to add one more feature for it, a random option, I have this bit of code worked out for how that will work.

```
set /a R=10 + %RANDOM% %% (99 - 10 + 1)
```

The only problem is, where this line of code is.

```
set /p code=Color Code:
```

It takes the user input, and gives it to the command (color %code%)
What I need is for it to distinguish "R"(My between 10-99 random number variable) as the variable %R% when it is typed. So when the user types "R" the window is changed to a random color.

I've tried an IF statement, but I'm not sure how to format it,here's what I tried.

```
set /a R=10 + %RANDOM% %% (99 - 10 + 1)
set /p code=Color Code:
if %code%="R" goto bottom
color %code%
cls
goto top
:top
echo Color Code: %code%
goto :eof
:bottom
color %R%
goto top
```

Comment: So you are saying the user has two options for input?  They can either enter the two character code using 0-9 and A-F, or they can type R to generate a random color?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Your random logic is not taking into account using the letters A-F.  Also you have no logic to test the errorlevel of the color command.  If the user or the random generates the same character for the background and foreground color it will produce an error and will not change the color. But essentially to answer your question, you will use the `IF` command to test if the `code` variable is equal to `R`.

Comment: I know it's not taking into account the A-F, but that's relativity unneeded, but yes, I've tried an "IF" statement, but I'm not sure how to put it

Comment: Update your code with what you have tried.

Comment: Here's what I've tried(keep in mind I'm not the best at batch coding, please don't tear me apart.)

Comment: It is a string comparison. If you have quotes on one side they have to be on the other side.

Comment: so how would i write that?

Comment: In order for the IF comparison to be true everything on the left side of the comparison also has to be on the right side of the comparison.  So `apple=="apple"` is not a true statement.  So based on that information, what would you put on the left side of the comparison to make it true.

Comment: if "R"=="R" goto bottom ???

Answer (score 0):

Alright, So with some studying, I've found out this!

If you are trying to make an IF ELSE statement with variables, it's pretty easy.

```
set /a (var)=(variable)
if "(var)"=="(What you're testing for)" (command)
```

So in my case the correct code would be.

```
set /a R=10 + %RANDOM% %% (99 - 10 + 1)
set /p code=Color Code:
if "%code%"=="R" goto bottom
color %code%
cls
goto top
:top
echo Color Code: %code%
exit
:bottom
color %R%
goto top
```